# Equivalent of Prototype in ES6

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, prototype

I am starting out in ES6 with background in JavaScript. I have a question. I have an ES6 class like the following:

```
class User{
 constructor(){
 }

 doSomething(){
 }
}
```

My questions is does `doSomething` method get created each time we instantiate this object? In previous JS, we could take out `doSomething` and create it with "prototype" to ensure that `doSomething` is created once, not every time we instantiate the object. However, I am note sure about the correct way to achieve the same effect in ES6. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> My questions is does "doSomething" method get created each time we instantiate this object?

No. The `class` syntax is more or less just [*syntactic sugar*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syntactic_sugar) for constructor function + prototype. I.e. the result is (almost) equivalent to:

```
function User() {}
User.prototype.doSomething = function() { };
```

Look at the result Chrome produces:

[image]

> However, I am note sure about the correct way to achieve the same effect in ES6.

As said, `class` does that for you. The whole point of introducing `class` is to make creating constructor functions and setting methods on `prototype` easier (hence *syntactic sugar*).

---

If you want to learn more, have a look at

- [MDN - Classes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes)

  > JavaScript classes introduced in ECMAScript 6 are syntactical sugar over JavaScript's existing prototype-based inheritance. The class syntax is **not** introducing a new object-oriented inheritance model to JavaScript. JavaScript classes provide a much simpler and clearer syntax to create objects and deal with inheritance.
- [YDKJS - ES6 & Beyond](https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/blob/master/es6%20%26%20beyond/ch3.md#classes)

Comment: It's worth noting that some people regard `class` as [syntactic poison](https://github.com/joshburgess/not-awesome-es6-classes).

Comment: It's relevant because the OP is asking about the "correct" way to do it in ES6, which means you should show both sides of the argument.

Comment: The difference I noticed is that class User doSomething appears both as instance method as well as inside `__proto__` of User object, while `User.prototype.doSomething` appears only inside `__proto__`. Not sure if this is Chrome console feature or in fact class methods are populated to every instance...

Answer (score 3):

Absolutely not. It seems no more binding method to prototype manually in ES6, but the fact is ES6 helps us to do that in background.
As MDN says:

> JavaScript classes introduced in ECMAScript 6 are syntactical sugar over JavaScript's existing prototype-based inheritance. The class syntax is not introducing a new object-oriented inheritance model to JavaScript. JavaScript classes provide a much simpler and clearer syntax to create objects and deal with inheritance.